# Flash `Stage.quality` affects `DisplayObject.transform.concatenatedMatrix` scaling

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stage

Adjusting the Flash stage quality by setting `stage.quality` appears to affect the matrix `DisplayObject.transform.concatenatedMatrix`:

```
import flash.text.TextField;

var child = new TextField();
var quals = ["best", "high", "16x16", "16x16linear", "8x8", "8x8linear", "low", "medium"];

for (var i in quals) {
    var qual = quals[i];
    stage.quality = qual;
    trace(qual + " TextField " + child.transform.concatenatedMatrix);
    trace(qual + " stage " + stage.transform.concatenatedMatrix);
}
```

The above code produces the following output (with the latest version of Adobe Animate, running in Flash Projector 35):

```
best TextField (a=5, b=0, c=0, d=5, tx=0, ty=0)
best stage (a=5, b=0, c=0, d=5, tx=0, ty=0)
high TextField (a=5, b=0, c=0, d=5, tx=0, ty=0)
high stage (a=5, b=0, c=0, d=5, tx=0, ty=0)
16x16 TextField (a=1.25, b=0, c=0, d=1.25, tx=0, ty=0)
16x16 stage (a=1.25, b=0, c=0, d=1.25, tx=0, ty=0)
16x16linear TextField (a=1.25, b=0, c=0, d=1.25, tx=0, ty=0)
16x16linear stage (a=1.25, b=0, c=0, d=1.25, tx=0, ty=0)
8x8 TextField (a=2.5, b=0, c=0, d=2.5, tx=0, ty=0)
8x8 stage (a=2.5, b=0, c=0, d=2.5, tx=0, ty=0)
8x8linear TextField (a=2.5, b=0, c=0, d=2.5, tx=0, ty=0)
8x8linear stage (a=2.5, b=0, c=0, d=2.5, tx=0, ty=0)
low TextField (a=20, b=0, c=0, d=20, tx=0, ty=0)
low stage (a=20, b=0, c=0, d=20, tx=0, ty=0)
medium TextField (a=10, b=0, c=0, d=10, tx=0, ty=0)
medium stage (a=10, b=0, c=0, d=10, tx=0, ty=0)
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation about this behavior - everything that I've read about the stage quality and display object transformations suggests they should be completely independent.

Some observations:

- `Stage.transform.matrix` is unaffected, suggesting that this scaling transformation is applied 'before' the stage transformation (as if the stage had a parent).
- The different `concatenatedMatrix` values all perform a scaling operation, with lower qualities appearing to result in *higher* scaling

What's the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

> *"What's the reason for this behavior?"*

I cannot confirm anything, no Flash IDE (or AS3 compiler) here, but...

The `scaleX` and `scaleY` numbers seem to be affected by how much pixel-grid area is assigned by the Anti-Aliasing (or smoothing) algorithm. The scale numbers are **divided with grid size** `N` (ignore the other  `x N` part).

If you're trying to **solve a problem about unwanted offsets** in your display objects then maybe you can use the formula to account for changes at different [Stage Qualities](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageQuality.html#BEST) (their NxN size)...

For example:

At **Low Quality** is your starting point of **no anti-aliasing**, so the value is `20` then you can see later how the `8x8 stage` becomes `20 / 8 = 2.5` ...

```
Type                pixel-grid      Matrix values
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

low stage           0 x 0           (a=20,      b=0, c=0, d=20,     tx=0, ty=0)

medium stage        2 x 2           (a=10,      b=0, c=0, d=10,     tx=0, ty=0)

high stage          4 x 4           (a=5,       b=0, c=0, d=5,      tx=0, ty=0)

best stage          4 x 4           (a=5,       b=0, c=0, d=5,      tx=0, ty=0)

8x8 stage           8 x 8           (a=2.5,     b=0, c=0, d=2.5,    tx=0, ty=0)

16x16linear stage   16 x 16         (a=1.25,    b=0, c=0, d=1.25,   tx=0, ty=0)
```

Comment: Also this 20 should relate to subpixel movement/placement of any children, the manual states that exact position of a `DisplayObject` could only be adjusted to 1/20th of a pixel pre-transformation. I hit that with some tower defense game where slowing a monster resulted in it moving less than that per frame and effectively getting locked in place.